# How Do I convert datetime-local input to unix timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

I am working with an input which type is `datetime-local`. I need to convert this to unix timestamp.

here's an example of what format the raw value submitted is `2018-06-12T19:30`.

I need to convert dates in formats such as the above into this format `1608954764`, the current unix timestamp.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. To answer your question you should try to provide some code (written by you), and then explain the actual behaviour and the behaviour you expect. [PHP Docu DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strtotime() will return a Unix epoch for the time given.

```
<?php
strtotime("2018-06-12T19:30");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use date_create_from_format.

date_create_from_format has the advantage to avoid system detecting wrong month and day (e.g. 2011-3-10 may mean 10 March or 3 Oct in different countries, but date_create_from_format is safe, it converts according to the rule you set)

As follows:

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-j H:i', str_replace('T',' ', '2018-06-12T19:30'));

echo $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime) is the easiest choice, but you really should consider using the `DateTime` class whenever possible.

To get the UNIX timestamp with `DateTime` simply use [`format('U')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
// returns UNIX timestamp as string
$ts = (new DateTime("2018-06-12T19:30"))->format('U');
```

There is also a shortcut for this called [`getTimestamp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```
// returns UNIX timestamp as int
$ts = (new DateTime("2018-06-12T19:30"))->getTimestamp();
```